Returning any struct that implements an Trait
In my codem I defined a trait Node, this trait is the "parent" of every trait that I use. How can I define a function that the return type is some struct that implements this trait? Currently the traits are defined this way:

pub trait Node {
    fn token(&self) -> Token;
}
pub trait Statement: Node {
    fn statement_node(&self);
}
pub trait Expression: Node {
    fn expression_type(&self) -> ExpressionType;
}

And I have two types of Node structs: Statement and Expression:
pub struct LetStatement {
    pub token: Token,
}
impl Node for LetStatement {
    fn node_type(&self) -> NodeType {}
}

impl Statement for LetStatement {
    fn statement_node(&self) {}
}


pub struct Expression {
    pub token: Token,
}
impl Node for LetStatement {
    fn node_type(&self) -> NodeType {}
}

impl Expression for LetStatement {
    fn statement_node(&self) {}
}

And in the simplified version of the function, I would have something like:
fn parse_statement(&mut self) -> Box<dyn Node> {
        match statement {
            "let" => self.parse_let_statement(),
            "return" => self.parse_return_statement(),
            _ => self.parse_expression_statement(),
        }
    }

The main problem with this approach is that with this return, all the structs returned from the helper functions gets "converted" into a Node, without the specific functions defined inside the traits expression and statement

You can return a generic trait which I think is figured out and the maximum area is allocated so it's not any performance benefit, but then I don't think you can use anything except what's defined in the trait itself so it's useless if I'm remembering right.  To get around this, enum of word(data1), sentence(data2), etc (I did that but it was years ago so don't know if anything changed)...

Note that for ASTs it is much better to use enums than traits.

If you want to be able to return one of many kinds of values, but have them retain their unique behaviors, you have a few options:

Provide some ability to downcast on your base trait (Node).
Provide all capabilities in a single trait.  Each capability necessarily must be fallible so that an error can be returned when the implementing type doesn't support the capability.
Return an enum instead of a trait.

Using an enum is far simpler than the other options, and is more idiomatic in Rust.
pub enum Node {
    Statement(Statement),
    Expression(Expression),
}

Given a Node, you can then match on it to inspect or extract the inner value.
match some_node {
    Node::Statement(stmt) => { stmt.statement_node(); }
    Node::Expression(expr) => { expr.expression_type(); }
}

Note that you may want to remove your traits altogether and use enums all the way down.  For example, Statement could be an enum with variants including Let(LetStatement).

Thank you for being so clear and thoughtful :)
